# Why does Image.SelectActiveFrame fail ("A generic error occured in GDI+") on last frame of a multi-page TIFF

Tags: .net, tiff

```
var frameCount = img.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page); // frameCount = 2
img.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, 0); // First frame selected with no issue
img.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, 1); // Exception: "A generic error occured in GDI+"
```